# Is there any meaning difference between "ran around without any shoes on" & "ran around with no shoes on"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

See this saying:

> I was so poor. I ran around without any shoes on. (googling it returns
>   9 results)
>
> I was so poor. I ran around with no shoes on. (googling it returns
>   4900 results)

Similarly,

> I have no friends
>
> I don't have any friends
>
> I have no money
>
> I don't have any money

Is there any meaning difference between "**ran around without any shoes on**" &  "**ran around with no shoes on**"?

Comment: They mean the same thing.

Comment: I agree that the mean the same thing, but they may feel different to the listener. For example, "I have no friends" might sound like a statement of fact to the listener and "I don't have any friends" might sound like a complaint. But this is all very contextual and possibly region-based.

Answer (score 2):

I would say there's a difference in emphasis.  In both cases, the person is barefoot.  *with no shoes* is a neutral statement of that fact, whereas *without any shoes* draws attention to the *absence* of shoes in situations where there is an expectation that shoes would be worn.

> We walked on the soft grass with no shoes on our feet.
>
> You can't enter the restaurant without any shoes.

It's not that you couldn't say the second sentence with **with no**, you can. **without any** simply makes the expectation that shoes are to be worn a little more strident.

Answer (score 1):

The most common term for the state of not wearing any footwear is ***[barefoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barefoot)***.

*Not to wear any shoes (on)* and *to wear no shoes (on)* both express the very same idea and although they are both acceptable [(see the Ngram Viewer)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=without+any+shoes%2Cwith+no+shoes%2Cbarefoot%2Cbarefooted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwithout%20any%20shoes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20no%20shoes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbarefoot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbarefooted%3B%2Cc0), in comparison to barefoot/barefooted they are used more rarely.

As for the difference, since the adjective "no" means "not any", there doesn't  seem to be any, so it would be quite acceptable to use any of the above, their frequency being kept in mind.